# Trouble understanding the limits of integration and application of Fubini's

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following system $$\begin{cases}
  \ddot{x} + p_1\dot{x} + p_2x = q,\\
  x(t_0)  = x_0\\
  \dot{x}(t_0) = x_1\\
 \end{cases}$$where $p_1,p_2$ and $q$ are all smooth functions. We claim it is possible to transform the previous system into an integral equation so that applying Banach fixed point theorem we get a unique solution for the system. To start, let $\varphi =\ddot{x}$. Then $$\dot{x} = x_1 + \int_{t_0}^t\varphi(s)ds,$$and \begin{align}
 x & = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t\dot{x}(s)ds\\
 & = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t\left(x_1 + \int_{t_0}^s\varphi(\tau)d\tau\right)ds\\
 & = x_0 + x_1(t-t_0) + \int_{t_0}^t\int_{t_0}^s\varphi(\tau)d\tau ds\\
 & = x_0 + x_1(t-t_0) + \int_{t_0}^t(t-s)\varphi(s)ds.
\end{align}

**Issues:**

(1) I lack the understanding of the limits of integration of $\int_{t_0}^t\int_{t_0}^s\varphi(\tau)d\tau ds$, I believe it must be $t_0 \leq \tau \leq s \leq t$ but I don't understand why.

(2) Then, we apply Fubini's so that $\int_{t_0}^t\left(\int_{t_0}^s\varphi(\tau)d\tau\right)ds = \int_{t_0}^s\left(\int_{t_0}^t\varphi(\tau)ds\right)d\tau = \int_{t_0}^s(t-t_0)\varphi(\tau)d\tau$. However this is different from $\int_{t_0}^t(t-s)\varphi(s)ds$.

Wondering if anyone could help me going through that last equality.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Draw a picture in the $s\tau$-plane of the region. You will have the triangle $\{(s,\tau): t_0\le s\le t, t_0\le\tau\le s\}$. Now $t_0\le\tau\le t$, and for each fixed $\tau$, we have $\tau\le s\le t$ (actually draw the ray and see where it enters and exits the region). ... To get the final integral they have renamed variables at the end (turning $\tau$ into $s$).

Comment: @TedShifrin I am sorry but I am not understanding how do we get a triangle. I am assuming we're working in 3 dimensions, those being $t,s,\tau$. Then, fixing $t > t_0 > 0$, we get a "rectangle" (since it won't have $s$ and $\tau$ limits, a rectangle is not a good word) by letting $s$ and $\tau$ running arbitrarily.

Comment: No, just in 2D. I said explicitly the $s\tau$-plane. $t$ is just a (fixed) parameter.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am sorry, what do you mean a fixed parameter? I was looking for an analytical approach but your method is intriguing me

Comment: $t$ is not a variable. It is a constant. Once you see the picture, you can make it as analytical as you want (I essentially made the argument in words in my first comment — you can put in the symbols).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the inner integral you have $t_0\le\tau \le s$. In the outer integral you have $t_0\le s\le t$. This can indeed be combined to the long chain of inequalities $t_0\le \tau \le s \le t$.

For Fubini or partial integration one changes the order of integration variables. Selecting $\tau$ as the outer variable then binds $s$ to the interval $\tau\le s\le t$, and $\tau$ can range from $t_0$ to $t$. So
$$
\int_{t_0}^t\int_{t_0}^s\varphi(\tau)\,d\tau\, ds
=
\int_{t_0}^t\left(\int_{\tau}^t\,ds\right)\varphi(\tau)\,d\tau
=
\int_{t_0}^t(t-\tau)\varphi(\tau)\,d\tau
$$
After that one has to switch the name of the integration variable from $\tau$ to $s$ to get the claimed result.

Comment: Ok, the chain of inequalities is indeed easy to see. Thanks. 
Now, regarding the integration: I feel like we're restricting our integration of the variable $s$ to $[\tau,t]$, but why can we do this, why not doing it on $[t_0,t]$? How do we know that we're not letting anything behind in $[t_0,\tau)$?

Comment: Because the n-integration domain in the $(s,\tau)$ plane is below the diagonal, this does not change when the integration is changed from vertical stripes to horizontal stripes.

Comment: Humm ok, I am not really secure. May I ask for some references to read something about this that we're talking about?

Comment: Sorry, new laptop, new keyboard layout. It is just an "integration domain", no "n-" decorations. // Just draw a lower-right triangle, then do an approximation by vertical "tall" rectangles, and then by horizontal bars. Note where they start and end.